# what does a if mean during variable assignment

Tags: linux, bash

I am going through a couple of BASH scripts. And I came across something like this

```
VAR_S=$(dd if=${MY_FILE} bs=16 count=1 skip=1024 iflag=skip_bytes 2>/dev/null | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"')
```

Apparently the Variable VAR_S should not be empty and I am trying to wrap my head around this statement. What does `if=${MY_FILE}` mean here. I am trying to figure out why VAR_S is returning empty when I echo it.It seems to me like `if` is a simple variable being assigned the value of `MY_FILE`. In that case I dont understand the significance of assignment and why not just use `dd ${MY_FILE}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `man dd` for explanation: `if` stands for "input file". These aren't variable assignments, but parameters. Variable assignment can't follow a command.

Comment: thanks could you also tell me the difference b/w $() and ${}. I know the ${Variable_NAME} outputs the variable but what is $() ?

Comment: `${var_name}` is the same as `$var_name`. `$(command)` is "Command substitution" (see `man bash`), it returns the output of the command as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Man file for DD.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html

You will notice that these are all parameters and not assignments.

Following is something I had used sometime back. Hope it helps.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/dd.htm